# Using curl command in java

Tags: java, curl

I have a curl command to use

```
curl -s -d user.name=xxxx \
       -d file=yyyy \
       -d arg=-v \
       'http://localhost:zzzz/templeton/v1/pig'
```

Can anybody tell equivalent java code for the above curl command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html` or take a [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/)

Comment: There are a lot of ways to send HTTP Post with Java, just google it, here is one of SO answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Answer (score 16):

Here a example show Processbuilder that executes curl.
These section of code work fine in my environment. Actually, you will executes it with no problems. The program obtains the image from web, and save as a jpg file. The jpg file is saved at the path "/home/your_user_name/Pictures".

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

  public class ProcessBuilderTest {

public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "curl",
            "-s",
            "http://static.tumblr.com/cszmzik/RUTlyrplz/the-simpsons-season-22-episode-13-the-blue-and-the-gray.jpg ");

    pb.directory(new File("/home/your_user_name/Pictures"));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            "/home/your_user_name/Pictures/simpson_download.jpg");

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    int numberByteReaded;
    while ((numberByteReaded = bis.read(bytes, 0, 100)) != -1) {

        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, numberByteReaded);
        Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) 0);

    }

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

}
 }
```

For your questions. It is the most directly and intuitively to map curl to Java code, when using 
Processbuilder. Just write as that:

```
curl -s -d user.name=xxxx \
-d file=yyyy \
-d arg=-v \
'htttp://localhost:zzzz/templeton/v1/pig'
```

become

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-s","-d user.name=xxxx ","-d `file=yyyy","-d   rg=-v" ,"htttp://localhost:zzzz/templeton/v1/pig");`
```