# Execute a curl command in java to a localhost

Tags: java, linux, apache, shell, curl

I'm a beginner with all this and I need to execute a docker command without using `sudo` in ubuntu to use the `gcc` compiler. 
In order to make that happen, a friend of mine wrote a script, in go lang, named http-to-shell and that is a program that listens as http server on  `http://localhost:4000`, and executes commands on terminal and returns output to client as a json response.

I run the command

```
sudo go run http-to-shell.go
```

and then on another tab i use commands like

```
curl -d command=ls http://localhost:4000
```

this works perfectly and then if I use

```
curl --data-urlencode "command@command.txt" http://localhost:4000
```

it runs the docker command that is in `command.txt` and shows the output of the program on the previous tab where i run `sudo` go run.

Now, my main issue. Since I'm a beginner I have no idea how to run this from a jsp page from localhost:8080 in ubuntu.

I have been trying, I tried using the answer in [Using curl command in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java)
but the process builder doesn't work. 
I need to run this curl command and get json response to show the user the output of his code.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Don't curl, use a http library for java to do the call

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? @Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the result of the json in your code then curl is probably not what you want. Curl is however pretty awesome if you want to do stuff from the command line, and yes there are Java curl bindings, but I'd personally use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Here is an example using HttpClient to do a REST call. 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/

The example uses Spring for the dependencies, I am not sure what your use, so you may have to download the jar yourself and place it on your class path

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, can you provide me with a sample on how to use it?

Comment: Hey. I found an answer on SOF in how to convert a php curl to java using httpurlconnection. I tried it but some how the command isn't being posted to the server. I set up another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272134/send-docker-command-to-localhost-using-httpconnection-jsp can you please check it and tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: that link seems to be deleted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291337/execute-terminal-command-in-java-with-httpurlconnection-and-get-response-in-json It's this one.