# Execute terminal command in java with httpurlconnection and get response in json format

Tags: java, json, jsp, curl, httpurlconnection

I have a localhost server running on port 4000 which listens to requests sent to it and executes commands and returns output to client in a json format.

I'm trying to send a request from tomcat's port 8080 to it and i need it to execute a command and send output back in json format.

I was able to do it through php using curl and the command executed but I need the solution in java so I made the following code:

```
public String sendData() throws IOException {
        // curl_init and url
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4000");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //  CURLOPT_POST
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        String postData = "ls"; //just trying a simple command
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(postData.length()));

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(postData);
        output.close();

        // "Post data send ... waiting for reply");
        int code = con.getResponseCode(); // 200 = HTTP_OK
        System.out.println("Response    (Code):" + code);
        System.out.println("Response (Message):" + con.getResponseMessage());

        // read the response
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        int c;
        StringBuilder resultBuf = new StringBuilder();
        while ( (c = input.read()) != -1) {
            resultBuf.append((char) c);
        }
        input.close();

        return resultBuf.toString();
    }
```

I'm getting a response `"OK"` and the default output of the port 4000. But the command doesn't execute.

Any idea what I'm missing? Or doing wrong?

**Edit on popular demand: The php curl function**

```
protected function HTTPRequest($url, $command){
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        $fields['command'] = $command;
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

`$url` here is `http://localhost:4000`

and `$command` is just any command is passed.

Comment: Did you check on your application running on port 4000? Did that receive the request ? Was it able to read the command successfully ?

Comment: Show us the working `curl` command please. And tell what's going on in your servlet. What seems strange to me is using `DataOutputStream`. Try it without it, just plain con.getOutputStream.

Comment: @ramp, with the php curl command, it does. But with the above java one doesn't. It only responds with the default response of the sever.

Comment: @hgoebl sure, I'll edit the question. And I'll try what you suggested too.

Comment: @hgoebl there is no output to con.getOuputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Your OutputStream cannot call any terminal command, because it's bound to your http connection only. To run terminal commands from the jvm, you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`
As an alternative you can use Apache Commons Exec, which I prefer.

Easiest way for you is to call your command in your function sendData(). Do it like this:

```
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // your output that you can use to build your json response:
        output.toString();
```

Comment: Okay so do I add it in this same function? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I had thought of this though, but didn't know where to implement it.