# How to send curl with java

Tags: java, curl

I need to send parameter in `curl request` but i don't about curl request.

Request is: How to send it in java.

```
curl --user xxx:xxxpass-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
'{"ImageId":"local",
  "ImageUrl":"http://www.gapcanada.ca/products/res/thumbimg/classic-fit-and-flare-dress-modern-red.jpg"}'

http://000.00.00.00:8080/api
```

Comment: Cann you tell us why you want to use cURL in Java? There are thousands of libraries out there.

Comment: i dont know .this is third party api i need to just pass few parameters

Comment: i have developed my web app in java

Comment: Then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/24053634/3621175

Comment: can you please share code here with my curl request. because i am not getting how to implement my request with this example

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'curl request'. `curl` is capable of sending requests in 23 existing formats according to the *man* page I found, most of which have existing Java implementations. You will have to tell us which format you're interested in. Then we will tell you you're off-topic..

Comment: curl --user xxx:xxxpass-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"ImageId":"local","ImageUrl":"http://www.gapcanada.ca/products/res/thumbimg/classic-fit-and-flare-dress-modern-red.jpg"}' http://000.00.00.00:8080/api

Comment: Hi EJP,  this is my curl request i am trying  to pass using java. and i dont know about this how to send this request

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to consume the API and somebody gave you the curl command as an example how to do so.

You now want to achieve the same in your JAVA program.

There are a few libraries which allow you to achieve this.
Google for «java http client post».

[Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)
or
[HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)
answers this is as well.

In your case this would be something like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("ImageId", "local");    
json.put("ImageUrl", "http://www.gapcanada.ca/products/res/thumbimg/classic-fit-and-flare-dress-modern-red.jpg");    

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://000.00.00.00:8080/api");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    httpClient.execute(request);
// handle response here...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}
```

Comment: thanx you so much i am trying it

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are better ways of doing this, but if for some reason you really want to use curl,

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("curl --user xxx:xxxpass-H \"Content-Type: 
    application/json\" -X POST -d
    \'{\"ImageId\":\"local\",
    \"ImageUrl\":\"http://www.gapcanada.ca/products/res/thumbimg/classic-fit-and-flare-dress-modern-red.jpg\"}\'"
```

Essentially, this Java function runs a command in terminal, so you can execute your request.

That is, for a post or put request. For get, just read it's output.

http://000.00.00.00:8080/api

If you want to send the request without having to install curl executables on the client system, look at Apache HttpClient library. :)

Comment: can you please explain little more

Comment: i am trying to post the request and please can you share the code how to implement my curl request

Comment: MY curl request is:   curl --user xxx:xxxpass-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
'{"ImageId":"local",
  "ImageUrl":"http://www.gapcanada.ca/products/res/thumbimg/classic-fit-and-flare-dress-modern-red.jpg"}'

http://000.00.00.00:8080/api

Comment: @IrshadQureshi Updated with more details and your request.

Comment: thank u so much arin