# Getting response of curl request in jsp

Tags: jsp, curl, wunderlist

There is a curl request working properly in terminal. You can copy paste following curl request in terminal as a command.

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
>   "code":"4be18766d47d4d60bfe9", "client_id": "e56693ca9d2c248f275d",
>   "client_secret":
>   "e2fc71d1d58679cc27b4f46ae6b4f2399519e9fdc8c99253531e186bd17b"}'
>   https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/access_token

you can see the output.
I want to run same curl request in jsp.  I wrote following code for it but its not generating output.

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line=reader.readLine();
while(line!=null)   { 
   out.println(line); 
   line=reader.readLine();
}
```

In curl request I use original values of my test case, so that you can get idea that what exactly I am asking. After getting answer I will change it.

Comment: You can look at this  for the idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java