# Convert Curl to java for stripe connect

Tags: java, arrays, curl

I'm trying to set up stripe connect (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) on my application, but I'm failing to set up the link between the platform and the standalone account. It provides a curl code to execute, and examples in ruby, python, PHP and node; but no java.

The curl call is as follows:

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \ -d client_secret=sk_test_IgHHUgcqKmxA8Yyai9ocqpZR \ -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \ -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

It looks pretty simple, but I have no idea how this works. I have been looking around trying to figure out how to make this call in java, and so far I haven't been able to.

Finally i got the correct code to run the curl command ,but it gives bunch of result.but i want only paricular id in it.how can i get that?

```
       `URL url = new URL("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("client_secret",API_KEY);
        params.put("code", code);
        params.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        String response = sb.toString();`
```

and i got 
`response={
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "livemode": false,
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "stripe_publishable_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "stripe_user_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "scope": "express"
}`

how can i get only the stripe_user_id in java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for that one using JSONObject,

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(response);
 String stripe_user_id=(String) jObject.get("stripe_user_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-d` parameters in `curl` are for POST data (see the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)). POST is the method for sending form data (e.g. when you submit a web form). Rather than putting the parameters on the end of the URL, like you would in a GET request, the parameters are encoded and sent inside the "body" of the request.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java) for various ways you can send POST data with requests from Java.

Alternatively, you could execute the `curl` process from Java. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to establish connections to outbound servers. [Here is an example](https://github.com/olivierbellone/stripe-java-examples/blob/18ebf1697e5f9cab5153d7ba28ea2ece3d9ec18a/stripe-oauth-spark2/src/main/java/com/stripe/StripeOAuthSpark2App.java#L79-L91) of a Stripe OAuth integration, using [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/).