# How do I call docker container using java commandline?

Tags: java, docker, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run docker container from inside a java application.

Code

```
String[] command = {"docker exec -it test_docker java -jar test.jar"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.inheritIO();
Process proc = pb.start();
```

While running the code I am getting an error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker exec -it test_docker java -jar test.jar": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.company.test.RunTask.main(RunTask.java:79)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Here is my container list,

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
f37c7ae71e12        tomcat:latest                  "/usr/local/tomcat/b"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                           tomcat_docker
f2cc2579b861        java:latest                    "/bin/bash"              2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:2377->2377/tcp                           test_docker
673c6617a0d5        mysql                          "docker-entrypoint.s"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:53306->3306/tcp                          mysql_docker
a76ca8d8f9e4        java:latest                    "/bin/bash"              2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                           Client
```

is it possible to run docker container command using java?
If possible then how do I execute using java?

Comment: Invoking a Java process within your code is not a very good way since this is not a "managed" way. Use the docker API or SDK for this purpose. Example https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/

Comment: I'm not sure if you can invoke `docker commands` in your java code. One way could be executing `curl command` in code through `docker API or SDK` as @ChathurangaChandrasekara suggested. check `http` tab of the doc. reference for `curl in java`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the way through which you can run docker command inside java.
There is a library available named **spotify/docker-client** on git [docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) using that you can run your docker command using java.It's easy to use library.

Here is a user manual [docker-client user_manual](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/blob/master/docs/user_manual.md)

Answer (score 3):

Try to split your command in an array like structure. as an example below

```
Process process;
String[] commandAndArgs = new String[]{ "/bin/sh","docker","exec","-it","test_docker","java","-jar","test.jar" };
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAndArgs);
```

set *Environment* and *Working Directory* both for your process. Since the error you are getting specifies *Unknown Source*, It can be ENVIRONMENT problem

```
java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

From Java docs you can see it states this exec() overloaded method

```
exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
```

Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

In case nothing stated works, I request you to kindly write a shell script file for your command and then set it executable using

```
chmod 755 or chmod +x script.sh;
```

then try to run that. I hope it works